# WP - Load a post's content into an empty div when it's title is selected in a list

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am building a site in wordpress where at a certain part there is a container that has a list of post items (see it as a menu/sidebar), and an empty space where I will load content. When you click on one of the titles from the list of posts, the content of that clicked title is supposed to load into the empty div. Clicking another title from the list of titles.

So it looks like this, basically:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="cats">
     <?php
       $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=10&cat=4');
       while ($my_query -> have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();  $category = get_the_category(); 
     ?>

       <li class="trigger">
         <h5>
           <? the_title(); ?>
         </h5>
       </li>

     <?php 
       endwhile; wp_reset_query(); 
     ?>
  </ul>
  <div class="the-content">
    <? the_content(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, I already looked up something for ajax but I don't have any experience with that. What would be the best way too do this?

Answer (score 0):

While you are getting post, you can also store post contents in a hidden div with an id specific to post. For example;

```
<?php
       $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=10&cat=4');
       while ($my_query -> have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();  $category = get_the_category();
echo '<div id="post_' . $my_query->the_post()->id . '" style="display:none;">' . $my_query->the_post()->content . '</div>'; 
 ?>
```

And when you click specific title, you can get related post content from hidden div;

```
<li class="trigger" onclick="showContent(this)" id="post_id">//This id must be the id of post
         <h5>
           <? the_title(); ?>
         </h5>
</li>
```

And javascript code;

```
function showContent(obj) {
    $(".the-content").empty().html($("#" + $(obj).attr('id')).html());
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Tried that but that just loads the title into the div, and does it only once. I get what this is supposed to do but the exact way is not what I'm looking for

Comment: If you want to do that with ajax, you can use ajax admin hooks. You can refer here http://w4dev.com/wp/wp_ajax/ . Basic logic is when clicking title, an ajax request will be send to admin-ajax.php with specific parameters that specifies your custom action. And that action will response post data to client